# Pandas plot barh with centered bars (pyramid)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to create a plot with pandas.plot(kind='barh') but get centered boxes around the middle of the plots (middle from an X axis perspective).

I tried to get something like this :
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/plots/top-50-matplotlib-visualizations-the-master-plots-python/#29.-Population-Pyramid

Using this code :

```py
ax = df.May2019.T.plot(kind='barh', subplots = False, stacked=True,
          figsize=(12,8), title = 'Number of customers per revenue slice',
          width=0.99)
vals = ax.get_yticks()
ax.set_yticklabels(['60%-80%', '40%-60%', '20%-40%', '0%-20%'])
ax.set_ylabel('Top x% Revenue')
ax.set_xlabel('Number of customers in revenue band')
```

I'm getting something like the below image which is to be expected :
[image: bar chart]

What I would be hoping is rather something that centers all the boxes in the middle of the chart. I get that the X axis would become sort of meaning less, but I'm looking for the value of the image.

My pd.Series looks like this

```py
0.8    75
0.6    26
0.4    10
0.2     3
Name: May2019, dtype: int64
```

Any suggestion as to what I should look at/change?

Comment: You can set `ax.set_xlim(-ax.get_xlim()[1], None)` to have the 0 in the middle of the axes. Is that what you mean? If not, please spend some more words describing the problem.

Comment: And also, please provide a code which can be simply copy pasted and executed to get the posted figure. Post the dataframe in a copyable format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the positive and negative halves:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
(df.May2019.T/2).plot(kind='barh',
                      title='Number of customers per revenue slice',
                      width=0.99, ax=ax)
(df.May2019.T/-2).plot(kind='barh', width=0.99, ax=ax)

ax.set_yticklabels(['60%-80%', '40%-60%', '20%-40%', '0%-20%'])
ax.set_ylabel('Top x% Revenue')
ax.set_xlabel('Number of customers in revenue band')
plt.show()
```

[image]